# HIstogram based feature extraction in an Image

Tags: image, image-processing, histogram, feature-extraction

I have an image which is subdivided into twelve ROIs. ROI is further divided into 10*10 pixel blocks. Now I want to compute features such as local contrast, minimum brightness ,sharpness, hue and saturation in each of these blocks , and plot 5 histograms(corresponding to each feature) for each of the ROI. I want to finally combine all histograms into one extended descriptor vector and use it for classification. Can someone please help me with a step wise approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. It seems to me you already have youth step-wise approach? I'd suggest you try to implement this and come back here when you get stuck. Then we'll have a more specific question to address.

Comment: As @Cris Luengo said, start working on each stage. you can search SO or google for each specific step  , try some code and then ask a question if you get stuck at specific stage. Here is an example of first step to find ROI. http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html